# Connecting the view controller to the code in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

When I create two view controllers in the main story board, how do I connect the second one to code?

An example would be:

- I put a label in the first view controller called `myLabel`
- I put another label in the second view controller called `myLabelTwo`

Now, the first view controller can connect to the code easily, but the second view controller 's `myLabelTwo` cannot be connected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new UIViewController class, ViewController2 for example
2. In your storyboard, select your second view controller and on the right side menu click on "Show the identity inspector"
3. Change the Class content to "ViewController2" or whatever else.
4. You can now connect "myLabelTwo" to your "viewController2"

Please check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) to understand storyboard and view controllers.